# How jquery event handle combine to one?

Tags: jquery, events

when i come to use jquery,it was more convenience than before,but some question will confuse me as below:
I have two anchors,and they have almost the same code,but i can't combine them to one.

```html
<a class="p" href="javascript:;">ABC</a>   
<a class="n" href="javascript:;">EFG</a>
```

```js
$(function(){

   var p = $('a.p');
   var n = $('a.n');

  p.on('mouseover',function(){
       $(this).css('color','red');
   }).on('mouseout',function(){
       $(this).css('color','black');
  });

  n.on('mouseover',function(){
     $(this).css('color','red');
  }).on('mouseout',function(){
     $(this).css('color','black');
  });

});

// You know it in javascript,we can do like this:

n[0].onmouseover = p[0].onmouseout = function(){ ....}

//and how about in jquery?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('a.p,a.n').on('mouseover',function(){
       $(this).css('color','red');
   }).on('mouseout',function(){
       $(this).css('color','black');
  });
});
```

See the docs for selecting multiple elements [here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: Do you need the second part in this or is this a copy-paste error? "n.on('mouseover',..." ?

Comment: @RyanLi You can't put both variables as the selector, but combine the selectors. So `$( "a.p, a.n" )` and discard the variables completely.

Comment: thx guy,I'm wrong.I wrote $('a.p','a.n') as well. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three ways. Combine the selectors:

```
$( 'a.p, a.n' ).on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).css('color','red');
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).css('color','black');
});
```

...or use the same function for both.

```
var mouseoverevent = function() {
    $(this).css('color','red');
};

var mouseoutevent = function() {
    $(this).css('color','black');
};

p.on('mouseover', mouseoverevent).on('mouseout', mouseoutevent);
n.on('mouseover', mouseoverevent).on('mouseout', mouseoutevent);
```

(The latter is a bit overkill in this simple example, but useful in more complex cases.)

If you want to keep the variables, the third way is to combine them:

```
p.add( n ).on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).css('color','red');
}).on('mouseout',function(){
    $(this).css('color','black');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use multiselector and hover..

```
$(function(){
  $('a.p,a.n').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('color','red');
  },function(){
    $(this).css('color','black');
  });
});
```